# enable Windows Authentication in Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, windows-8.1

I am trying to start a visual studio MVC project with IIS.  Here are the instructions for enabling Windows authentication:

```
  To enable Windows authentication on Windows:
  a) In Control Panel open "Programs and Features".
  b) Select "Turn Windows features on or off".
  c) Navigate to Internet Information Services > World Wide Web Services > Security
     and make sure the Windows authentication node is checked.
```

Following those instructions, here is what I see.  I don't see a Windows Authentication node.  How can I enable it?

[image]

Comment: I was able to follow your instructions, and it worked for me. Thanks for your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Windows 7, Windows Authentication is only available for:

- Ultimate
- Professional
- Enterprise Editions

I would imagine, since the option is not available to you, this has not changed for Windows 8.  Unless you can confirm you are running one of these versions that is!

Not available for:

- Windows 7 Home Premium Edition
- Windows 7 Home Basic and Starter Editions

[Windows Authentication is not supported Home or Starter editions of Windows Vista® and Windows® 7.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754628%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: I don't think these restrictions apply to IIS. You're talking about running from a version of VS.

Comment: ah. yup, you're correct. Sorry. I thought you misunderstood the question, but instead I misunderstood your answer :)

Comment: Since the title of the original post mentions 8.1 I thought i should mention that this feature requires upgrading 8.1 to 8.1 pro, not immediately obvious or cheap (£100). This is a deal breaker for me so will roll back to Windows 7

Comment: I don't even know why they let you install WebDAV on Windows 8.1 Home when you can't authenticate with it.